# Set display property depending on the size of the number in the span tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to decide whether I can see the image or not depending on the size of the number in the span tag.

```
<TIME>TIME : <span id="TIME">0</span>  </TIME>
<img src="sun.png" id="sun" class="sun">
<img src="clock.png" id="clock" class="clock"  height="128px" width="128px" onclick="addToTIME(1)">



<script>
    if ($("#TIME").text() <= 6)
    {
        $('#sun').css('display', 'none');
    }
</script>
```

But my code doesn't work.

Comment: Your code works for me, try with document ready:
`$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($("#TIME").text() <= 6) {
    $("#sun").hide(); //$('#sun').css('display', 'none');
  }
});`

Comment: Did you remember to add a reference to jQuery? If you open the browser's "Developer Tools" (press F12) and go to the "Console", there could be an error message like "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined."

Comment: @whoiswho   If I use this script to raise the value of Spandex, does the code not understand?      var TIME = 0;
        function addToTIME (amount) {
            TIME = TIME + amount;
            document.getElementById("TIME").innerHTML = TIME;
        };

Comment: @AndrewMorton I added jquery script source. Thank you for asking!

Comment: How is the text in the #TIME element getting updated? Do you want your code to run when it changes?

Comment: @AHaworth   like this '< ~ onclick="addToTIME(1)">   <script>var TIME = 0; function addToTIME (amount) { TIME = TIME + amount; document.getElementById("TIME").innerHTML = TIME; }; </script>' Yes I really want.

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding sun from the start but never set it back to `display:block`

```js
var TIME = 0;

function addToTIME(amount) {
  TIME = TIME + amount;
  document.getElementById("TIME").innerHTML = TIME;
  controlTheSun()
};

$(document).ready(controlTheSun)

function controlTheSun() {
  if ($("#TIME").text() <= 6) {
    $('#sun').css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $('#sun').css('display', 'block');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TIME>TIME : <span id="TIME">0</span>  </TIME>
<img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/chudtsankov/chudtsankov1207/chudtsankov120700038/14510469-summer-hot-sun.jpg?ver=6" id="sun" class="sun" height="128px" width="128px">
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/812L5zyAmpL._AC_SX522_.jpg" id="clock" class="clock" height="128px" width="128px" onclick="addToTIME(1)">
```

Comment: Thanks to this code, I solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @yooyoo01 In case you haven't seen it before: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)